# Cant connect to my visible network

Tags: networking, updates

My ubuntu did an automatic update and now my laptop wont connect to the internet. It shows visible networks but will not connect to them. Help! I am a newbie and learning to use and navigate Linux. I have an android tablet and connects just fine. On the laptop it shows the wifi symbol all black in the network settings but on the top far right it shows 3 little dots,showing there is a network, it can read it but wont connect to it. I went in an disabled the IPV6 but that did nothing.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: I've also tried connecting at my sister's house, so it's not my internet modem, it's my computer that isn't letting me connect

Comment: I can log onto my wifi Hotspot but not a modem